# How to add a column with computed columns with values of row on Sybase IQ

Tags: sybaseiq

How to add a computed column to a table referring a field from current row at Sybase IQ 16

Here is want I want to achieve: 
When inserting a new row (or updating a row) I want to have a column updated based on a function referencing another field. To make an example

I've got this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "myTable" (
    id integer,
    sales integer,
    bonus integer
)
```

Where bonus should be calculated as sales * 10 -- remember, just an example.

I was thinking about adding some trigger functions doing this, but then I found computed columns -- unfortunately wasn't able to get this running.

Comment: Quoi?  Please clarify what you are asking!

Comment: Updated question a little ;)

Comment: What does the manual/documentation say about computed columns and what did you try?

Comment: 1 min search and the [Sybase infocenter: SAP Sybase IQ 16: `CREATE TABLE` statement](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1603/doc/html/san1281564827401.html) shows no mention of computed columns.

Comment: But alter table does -- and that's why I'm asking. Also it appers to be possible via Control center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page [Considerations When Using the `CREATE TABLE` Statement](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1602/doc/html/san1278453552353.html) from the Sybase IQ 16 online manual:

> Computed Columns
>
> Computed column support differs as follows:
>
> - SAP SQL Anywhere supports computed columns that can be indexed.
> - Adaptive Server Enterprise and **SAP Sybase IQ do not.**

---

It seems to support views though, so you could define a view that contains the columns of the table plus the function, as another column (the column values will not be materialized this way, only computed when needed.)